A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-screens'. k\26.1.10909125 did not have a source.properties file

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. `* What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-screens'. k\26.1.10909125 did not have a source.properties file Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights. Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.`

How to handle that problem??? `Did I make a mistake in configuring or was I wrong in recognizing the problem and how to solve it?

Did you read the error message? What happened when you actually ran gradle with the flags it mentions? Please also check [ask].

In your project, go to android/build.gradle. Change your ndkVersion to this version: ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888". It works fine on my side.

Solved this by manually downloading the NDK version 26.1.10909125 from https://github.com/android/ndk/releases and put its content into the  /ndk/26.1.10909125 folder
